# EF Query for multiple conditions

Tags: entity-framework

Referring to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data

```
// Load one blog and its related posts.
var blog1 = context.Blogs
                   .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog")
                   .Include(b => b.Posts)
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Say under Posts we have a flag field having values Y or N

How to rewrite the above to fetch blogs with Name "ADO.NET Blog" **AND** Posts with Flag =Y

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Load one blog and its related posts.
var blog1 = context.Blogs
                   .Where(b => b.Name == "ADO.NET Blog")
                   .Include(b => b.Posts.Where(p => p.Flag == 'Y'))
                   .FirstOrDefault();
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data/eager#filtered-include